Warning: Ie: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead

Warning: Ie: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.

I am using next 14.2.10 version this warning occurs
Kindly give me global solution
If I send default props in that it work fine but i don't think this is the best way to solve this issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
